# Match process between right answers and randomly selected student grades

Tags: java, arrays

I'm working on a test question

There are 12 students that I determine their names, IDs and surnames. There are also 3 different groups: 0, 1, and 2. In each group, there are 4 students.

The test question wants me to use arrays and match student's answers with the key (ten questions with five possible answers)

However, I cannot do a matching process between correct answers and the students' answers because both are `char`'s, correct?

Below is my code:

```
import java.util.Random;
public class YEAH
{
    private static final Random randomChar=new Random();

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String studentID[][] = new String [2][3];
        String  studentName[][]= new String[3][4];
        String  studentLastName[][]= new String [3][4];
        studentName[0][0]="Cagatay";
        studentName[0][1]="Serhat";
        studentName[0][2]="Ozan";
        studentName[0][3]="Kadir";
        studentName[1][0]="Büsra";
        studentName[1][1]="Ekin";
        studentName[1][2]="Hakan";
        studentName[1][3]="Begum";
        studentName[2][0]="John";
        studentName[2][1]="Josh";
        studentName[2][2]="Igor";
        studentName[2][3]="Vladimir";
        studentLastName[0][0]="Cevik";
        studentLastName[0][1]="Atmaca";
        studentLastName[0][2]="Baykus";
        studentLastName[0][3]="Korkusuz";
        studentLastName[1][0]="Dede";
        studentLastName[1][1]="Akarcay";
        studentLastName[1][2]="Demir";
        studentLastName[1][3]="Daskaya";
        studentLastName[2][0]="Kennedy";
        studentLastName[2][1]="Williams";
        studentLastName[2][2]="Ruski";
        studentLastName[2][3]="Putin";
        studentID[0][0]="B1";
        studentID[0][1]="B2";
        studentID[0][2]="B3";
        studentID[0][3]="B4";
        studentID[1][0]="C1";
        studentID[1][1]="C2";
        studentID[1][2]="C3";
        studentID[1][3]="C4";
        studentID[2][0]="D1";
        studentID[2][1]="D2";
        studentID[2][2]="D3";
        studentID[2][3]="D4";
        char key[]={'a','b','c','e','d','b','a','b','a','e'};
        int studentmark[][]=new int[3][4];
        String studentanswer[][]=new String[12][10];
    }

    static void displayGrades(char a [][])
    {
        String alphabet="abcde";
        for (int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
            for(int j=0;j<a[i].length;j++)
                a[i][j]=alphabet.charAt(randomChar.nextInt(5));
```

Comment: *But;i cannot do match process between correct answers and student's answer because;both of them are char,right?* Is there an error? Whats the problem in comparing chars?

Comment: Because in the method,if i try to print the students' correct answerx10;how it can be possible ? Method cannot see the things in main

Comment: Give us the full code you wrote, because so far you don't have any comparisons. And what is the purpose of 'displayGrades'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have read your comment and I think you just need to place ID, name, lastName variables outside of your main function and make them **static**. You can also do this with the key array. This way other methods can work with these variables.

```
import java.util.Random;
public class YEAH {
    private static final Random randomChar=new Random();

    private static String studentID[][] = new String [3][4];
    private static String studentName[][]= new String[3][4];
    private static String studentLastName[][]= new String [3][4];
    private static char key[]={'a','b','c','e','d','b','a','b','a','e'};

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //your code here...
    }
    //...
```

**EDIT**
**EDIT2**

So this code will count the points of each person and displays it. Hope it helps.

```
import java.util.Random;
public class YEAH
{
    private static final Random randomChar=new Random();
    private static String studentID[][] = new String [3][4];
    private static String studentName[][]= new String[3][4];
    private static String studentLastName[][]= new String [3][4];
    private static char key[]={'a','b','c','e','d','b','a','b','a','e'};
    private static int studentPoints[][]=new int[3][4]
    private static int studentGrades[][]=new int[3][4];  //points*10
    private static char[][][] studentAnswers = new char[3][4][10];
        //store the answers given by students

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        studentName[0][0]="Cagatay";
        studentName[0][1]="Serhat";
            //... your code ...
        studentID[2][2]="D3";
        studentID[2][3]="D4";
        generateRandomAnswers();
        countPoints();
        PrintResults();
    }

    private static void PrintResults() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            {
                System.out.Println(studentPoints[i][j] + "\t" +
                    studentID[i][j] + "\t" +
                    studentName[i][j] + "\t" +
                    studentLastName[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void countPoints() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++)
                {
                    studentPoints[i][j] = 0;
                    if (studentAswers[i][j][k] == key[i][j][k])
                    {
                        studentPoints[i][j]++;
                    }
                    studentGrades[i][j] = 10 * studentPoints[i][j];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static void generateRandomAnswers() {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        String alphabet="abcde";
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++)
                {
                    studentAnswers[i][j][k]=alphabet.charAt(randomChar.nextInt(5));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: in the assignment;        displayGrades method: displays the grade of students together with student ID, name and last name to the screen as a table. The table should have a nice heading,so i follow this path

Comment: static void displayGrades(char a [][])
    {
        String alphabet="abcde";
        for (int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
            for(int j=0;j<a[i].length;j++)
                a[i][j]=alphabet.charAt(randomChar.nextInt(5));

Comment: i have to use in a method which is called 'Displaygrades' / In the main method,call this method

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
 at YEAH.main(YEAH.java:44)  why do i take this error?

Comment: Thanks for everything,i appreciate

Comment: i have some problem about this question,i need grade system,for each correct answer,answer must be got 10 points ,but i can't create a method :(

Comment: Nope i have to determine the grades of each student according to their studentpoints array // for example;randomly for first student take 5 points from exam,his grade will be 5 x 10 ,each question is 10 point i mean

Comment: Yes,thanks for your mentoring :)   I'm at the beginner level and always try to learn but sometimes i cannot see the errors or the right way to reach,so i need this kind of help.Without my own effort,i don't ask anything

Comment: @ÇağatayÇevik can you and Tamas clean-up the comments a bit that are no longer relevant and/or move stuff to the answer?